# Running postgres functions with Sequelize js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to run a function from sequelize.js against my postgres database.  The function works fine when I run it through RazorSQL (database IDE), but it throws an error when running it from sequelize.js on a node server.

I tried it for both functions with and without parameters.

CoffeeScript on Node Server

```
query = "SELECT * FROM order.base_orders(); "

sequelize.query(query, null, {raw: true}).success (rows) =>
  deferred.resolve rows
.error (error) =>
  deferred.reject error
```

It returns the following error.

```
{
"error": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 216,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42883",
    "hint": "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
    "position": "15",
    "file": "parse_func.c",
    "line": "306",
    "routine": "ParseFuncOrColumn",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM order.base_orders(); "
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it a bit wrong. functions can only by called at the columns selection area. like

```
select function(arguments)
```

in sequelize it will be like this

```
const query = "SELECT searchProducts('search query');"
return sequelize.query(query);
```

note that sequelize is my Sequelize db session that I created like below

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error says: you need to cast your data, e.g. `select foo((?)::int)`, or make sure you're calling it with the correct number of arguments -- or make sure it exists, for that matter.